# d3 zoomable treemap JSON value attributes

Tags: json, d3.js, zooming, treemap, accessor

It looks as though the attribute we use in the JSON to specify the rectangle size must be named "value" otherwise Mike's code at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/ won't work.

I tried replacing "value" with "amount" in the JSON and changing the Javascript accordingly but that doesn't seem to work. All the rects end up on top of each other at 0,0.

Then I tried specifying the value accessor to use (as per the API docs: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Treemap-Layout) by adding an extra line to Mike's example:

```
var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
.children(function(d, depth) { return depth ? null : d._children; })  
.sort(function(a, b) { return a.value - b.value; }) 
.ratio(height / width * 0.5 * (1 + Math.sqrt(5)))  
.round(false)  
.value(function(d){ return d.amount; });      // This line added by me
```

But that didn't get the desired result by itself. (I kept all other references in the code to d.value.)

Can anyone else confirm this? It could trip someone else up too. The documentation (same link as above) says that the JS object nodes all end up with a "value" attribute but I expect that there is a proper way to import a JSON with other names for the numerical field.

Comment: It sounds like it should work. Could you post a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Thanks, Lars. Please see http://democra.me/treemap.htm. This is essentially Mike's example, but with the extra line as above and my own JSON file (budget_amount.json). It works fine if I use budget_value.json instead which is also on the server.

Comment: @MSC Other parts of the code need to be changed as well, for example, the `accumulate` function. You can play with the fiddle in my response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the accessor function, it will give the desired results. Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/63Edr/) with value renamed to amount.

Pertinent sections of code:

```
...
{"name": "Great Powers", "amount": 3938, ...}, // changed from "value" to "amount"
...

var treemap = d3.layout.treemap()
    .value(function(d) {return d.amount})  // IMPORTANT
    ...
    .sort(function(a, b) { console.log(a.amount); return a.amount - b.amount; })
    ...

function accumulate(d) {
    return (d._children = d.children)
        ? d.amount = d.children.reduce(function(p, v) { return p + accumulate(v); }, 0)
        : d.amount;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @FernOfTheAndes! I thought I'd tried that combination but obviously not.